# Selenium .Click() inconsistent behavior across machines in firefox using C#

Tags: c#, firefox, selenium

I am using Firefox 28, Web Driver v2.41, and C#.

I have the following simple test (anyone can replicate. I have added the horrible wait to demonstrate that this is not an issue related to the page not being ready):

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var FF = new FirefoxDriver();
        FF.Navigate().GoToUrl(@"http://www.bing.com");
        FF.FindElement(By.Id("sb_form_q")).SendKeys("Stack Overflow");
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        FF.FindElement(By.Id("sb_form_go")).Click();
    }
```

The test behaves as expected in machine A.

The test **fails to perform the click on the last line in machine B** (Lenovo W530). The click method is not working with ANY of my tests on this machine.

If I switch the .Click() for .SenKeys(Keys.Enter) then the problem is solved.

Comment: Couple of things, are both machines running the same environment? Same Firefox versions? Same profile? Same extensions? Same Windows versions? Same WebDriver version? Same version of Visual Studio? Also, it appears that have Windows use the larger/medium font sizes (changeable within the 'Display' setting) causes intermittent failures like this. So check this setting on both machines.

Comment: could be [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=6112) ?

Comment: The issue refers to V23 of Firefox. I am on V28. However, I will check my text size to find out if that makes a difference.